# Форматирование телефонных номеров к единому виду

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, format

Имеем файл с базой данной. Почистила его от пропусков и переименовала в `data2`

> как в столбце `Tel1` преобразовать номера разного формата

```
'8-902-657-09-50; 8(8442) 94-39-54; 89272555572; (884463) 2-64-71; 
 8> 903 371 40 73'
```

в единый формат `+7-777-777-77-77`

> (только русские номера)? возможно по аналогии со временем

```
'print(pd.something('01-mar-2016', format='%d-%b-%Y'))'
```

как точно не могу понять

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Я  советую хранить номера без форматирования, а форматировать  после извлечения

Comment: Используйте regexp и map у pandas. regex заранее скомпильте, чтобы по времени не так много занимало

Comment: @MrMorgan могли бы вы уточнить как? я новичок

Comment: @user329688, я уже дважды давал вам ссылку на то как лучше всего оформить вопрос по обработке данных. В вопросе должен присутствовать воспроизводимый пример данных в таком виде, чтобы людям, которые хотят вам помочь, не пришлось "вбивать" его руками. Также необходимо показать что вы хотите получить на выходе (в качестве результата). Т.е. в вашем случае вам надо привести в вопросе все возможные варианты написания телефона и привести выходной /желаемый вариант написания для всех входных телефонов. Удачи вам! :)

Comment: Кстати. А не нарушаете ли вы права этих людей, выкладывая на всеобщую обозримость их адреса, имена и номера телефонов?

Comment: @MrMorgan, почистили.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
telList = ['8-902-657-09-50;',
           '8(8442) 94-39-54;',
           '89272555572;',
           '(884463) 2-64-71;',
           '8> 903 371 40 73']

newTelList = [ ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, tel)) for tel in telList ]

[ print('+{}-{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(tel[0], tel[1:4], tel[4:7], tel[7:9], tel[9:11])) for tel in newTelList]
+8-902-657-09-50
+8-844-294-39-54
+8-927-255-55-72
+8-844-632-64-71
+8-903-371-40-73
```

---

Update

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.  ], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
     'Tel1' : pd.Series(['8-902-657-09-50', 
                         '8(8442) 94-39-54;', 
                         '89272555572;', 
                         '(884463) 2-64-71;'], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print("\ndataframe:\n", df)

print("\nCтолбец Tel1:", type(df['Tel1']), df['Tel1'], sep='\n')

dfToList = df['Tel1'].tolist()

print("\ndfToList:", dfToList, " type dfToList:", type(dfToList), sep='\n')
print()

newTelList = [ ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, Tel1)) for Tel1 in dfToList ] 

[ print('+{}-{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(Tel1[0], Tel1[1:4], Tel1[4:7], Tel1[7:9], Tel1[9:11])) for Tel1 in newTelList ]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я попробовала преобразовать столбец в лист(так как мне нужно вывести полную таблицу с отформатированными номерами) 'data2.Tel1 = list
newTelList = [ ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, tel)) for tel in data2.tel ]
[ print('+{}-{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(tel[0], tel[1:4], tel[4:7], tel[7:9], tel[9:11])) for tel in newTelList]' ошибка 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tel'

Comment: data2.Tel1 = list
newTelList = [ ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, Tel1)) for Tel1 in data2.Tel1 ]
[ print('+{}-{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(Tel1[0], Tel1[1:4], Tel1[4:7], Tel1[7:9], Tel1[9:11])) for Tel1 in newTelList]. вот такая ошибка 'type' object is not iterable.  @S.Nick

Comment: @user329688 посмотрите обновление в ответе

Comment: верно @S.Nick  , код работает для тех телефонов, которые вбиты вами вручную. Нужно, чтобы все телефоны в базе (их около 3 тысяч) в таблице отформатировались, при это мне отдельно, а в ней самой. попробовала такой код: 'data3 = pd.DataFrame(data2).  

ToList = data2['Tel1'].tolist()

newTelList = [ ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, Tel1)) for Tel1 in ToList ] 

[ print('+{}-{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(Tel1[0], Tel1[1:4], Tel1[4:7], Tel1[7:9], Tel1[9:11])) for Tel1 in newTelList ] '     TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Comment: @user329688, советую вам оформить вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать адекватный ответ... Кстати, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и/или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814) ;)

Comment: это Пайтон, детка!
круть!

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться модулем `re` из стандартной библиотеки python

```py
import re

# в самом начале
NUM_RE = re.compile(r".*(\d).*(\d).*(\d).*(\d).*(\d).*(\d).*(\d).*(\d).*(\d).*(\d).*")

... # ваш код

# в процессе. df - ваша таблица
df['Tel1'] = df['Tel1'].apply(lambda x: "+7" + ''.join(NUM_RE.match(x).groups()))
```

Формат будет `+78008008080`

`NUM_RE` берёт 10 чисел из строки, пропуская все другие символы. Притом, если символов больше, он возьмёт 10 последних. Однако, если чисел меньше, ваша программа вызовет исключение.

[Тут](https://regex101.com) можете почитать и попрактиковаться в regexp

А [тут](https://tproger.ru/articles/regexp-for-beginners/) имеется информация для новичков